# How to put an Vertical scrollbar within asp:Repeater ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, scrollbar, panel, ascx, asprepeater

I have inherited an .ascx control that consists of an asp:repeater construct containing a HeaderTemplate, an ItemTemplate and an empty FooterTemplate.

Both the header and the item templates are linked to a data source.

My question is simply this, I want to have a vertical slider applied to the ItemTemplate such that I can scroll up and down the items contained within whilst the HeaderTemplate remains static.

I have tried using an asp:Panel within the ItemTemplate but this doesn't render the row within the template.

I've resorted to encapsulating the whole of the asp:Repeater within an asp:Panel that specifies a vertical scrollbar. This works but scrolls the header out of view if the number of rows in the ItemTemplate is large.

If anyone can help and suggest a way forward I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in a simple manner with some CSS tricks e.g.

**Repeater Item  Template Markup**

```
<HeaderTemplate>
  <div class="template">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    Your Stuff
 </ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
  </div>
</FooterTemplate>
```

**CSS Defined for "template"**

```
.template {
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: You're very kind. Thanks I will give it a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because it simply inserts a scrollbar for each row in the ItemTemplate. Thank you all the same for replying.

Comment: @MPG, I have edited my answer and move the template div in header template and closed it in footer template. This will certainly fix your issue.

Comment: I'm really sorry for such a late reply but thank you Kundan for your kind reply.